# not accepting conversion out of range mysql go decimal

Tags: mysql, go

I am writing a Go program that communicates with MySQL.

I have the following column:

```
lot_size double(8,8)
```

I'm ingesting an xml feed and parsing it in Go. Here is the data dump of the `lot_size xml data`

```
(string) (len=4) "0.36"
```

Also, sometimes it can be:

```
(string)  ""
```

In my Go program, I have the following conversion:

```
 if listings.Listings[i].LotSize == "" {
    lotSize=0.00000000
 } else {
    lotSize,_=strconv.ParseFloat(listings.Listings[i].LotSize,8)
 }
```

Mysql is producing the following error:

`Error 1264: Out of range value for column 'lot_size' at row 1`

Not sure what to do at this point

UPDATE

HERE is the parsed float data output:

```
(float64) 0
34 (float64) 0.410239
35 (float64) 0.045914
36 (float64) 0.325941
37 (float64) 0.208425
38 (float64) 0.078627
39 (float64) 0.132989
40 (float64) 0.163522
41 (float64) 0.24
42 (float64) 0.230119
43 (float64) 0
44 (float64) 4.25
```

my sql query is:

`insert into listings (lot_size) values (?)`

```
stmt,err:=db.Prepare(sqlStatement)
res,err:=stmt.Exec(lotSize)
```

Comment: Do not use block quotes for proper nouns such as `MySQL`, or terms like `go program`. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/13860).

Comment: The error means that you're trying to store values that don't fit into the column, in this case any number >= 1, because of the at most eight digits eight must be after the decimal point. The code you show here has nothing to do with the error, but it is certainly incorrect because you are confusing bits with number of digits.

Comment: @Peter but its a decimal 8,8 and im inserting a float of 8 decimals?

Comment: If you were you wouldn't get the error. Obviously we can't verify code we can't see.

Comment: @Peter what am i missing from the question? i made it pretty explanatory

Comment: ill dump the converted string hold please

Comment: You are missing that you want help with a MySQL error but you show code that doesn't interact with MySQL at all.

Comment: i fixed it. i made the columns decimal (12,8)

Answer (score 1):

The answer discussed in comments above boils down to this:

MySQL `FLOAT(8,8)` type means the value may have eight digits, but *all eight* must be to the right of the decimal. This means any value 1.0 or greater cannot be stored in this column if you declare a `FLOAT` with two argument that are the same number.

This behavior is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

By the way, this nonstandard form of `FLOAT` with two arguments is deprecated in MySQL 8.0.17 and will be removed in a future version of MySQL. It's recommended to use `DECIMAL` instead.

Comment: Made this answer community wiki because the answer was found in comments above.